# How to branch multiple projects in one solution using subversion?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a VS2010 solution that contains multiple projects. We have this entire tree in SVN and are working on branching the entire tree so that we can begin work on version 2. We used the TortoiseSVN plugin for Windows Explorer and tried to branch from the top of the physical tree in Windows Explorer. It seems that not all of the projects down in the tree were actually put on the branch, although some of them were. Is there some way to branch the entire solution (all projects) or do we have to branch each project individually? We have a folder for each project in the physical tree.
thanks!
Bill

Comment: Are there svn:externals references in your tree?

Answer (score 2):

I do this all of the time with TortoiseSVN.  Just right-click the folder (trunk) and choose Branch, and enter the branch location in your repo.  If some of the folders weren't branched, that sounds like you didn't add the projects to your trunk.

Another possibility, is that you merged a branch at one point, then reverted (which leaves the folder there), and thought it was still merged.  Your code would compile (if your branch did), but when you do all future commits, the other folders won't get committed.

The best thing to do is to go into the repo browser and drill down into your main folder.  Ensure that all of the projects are there.  If they are, try branching from the repo browser, though that shouldn't make a difference.

Ever time I've encountered a problem with SVN seemingly doing something wrong, it's because of a strange, unintentional user action or mistake.

Hopefully some of this info will help you figure out the problem.  Good luck!

Comment: Dave - thanks for the suggestions. We have had this project on the truck for about 5 months now and this is the first time we've tried to branch. i think all the projects are in subversion. We get everything when we CheckOut.

Comment: @Bill Campbell yikes.... have you tried to branch directly from the repo browser?

Comment: No - we haven't. :(  All the work so far has been on the main trunk but I am confident that all the projects are in SVN. I just can't figure out why some would branch and others wouldn't. Like you said, probably something we did. We'll try from the Repo. Thanks!